# I am trying to solve the error message 'incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment' in a fortran 95 program.

Tags: fortran

I am writing a program in Fortran to find the velocity of a parachuting person in relation to time. I keep getting an error that I can't fix. I am very new to programming and any help is greatly appreciated.

The error is

```
v(i+1)=v(i)+[32-((c*v(i)*v(i))/m)]*(h)
1
```

Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)

and my program is

```
PROGRAM para
INTEGER :: i
REAL :: v(11) !velocity
REAL :: q !initial velocity
REAL :: h !time step
REAL :: c !drag coefficient
REAL :: m !mass

! gravity is equal to 32 ft/s^2

WRITE (*,*)'enter time step'
READ(*,*)h

Write(*,*)'enter initial velocity'
READ(*,*)q

WRITE(*,*)'enter drag coefficient'
READ(*,*)c

WRITE(*,*)'enter mass'
READ(*,*)m

DO i=1,10 ! from 1 to 10, with 1 being the interval.
END DO

v(i+1)=v(i)+[32-((c*v(i)*v(i))/m)]*(h)

q=v(1)
```

END PROGRAM

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `[]` as a normal parenthesis in expressions. It is an array constructor, `[ items ]` means an array with items as elements. Also the `end do` should be after this line.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you span up a vector using `[ ... ]` (this is equivalent to `(/ ... /)`). So, using regular brackets instead of the square ones solves your problem.

BTW: I'm a little confused about your loop... Shouldn't the `v(i+1) = ...` line be inside the loop?